# Test covergae is showing 0

Tags: java, testing, junit, mockito, test-coverage

I want to write an test class for my controller class

I have written a test class for my controller class but having 0 coverage. The work is to follow a category and unfollow a category

This is my category class

public class Category {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String categoryName;
@ManyToMany
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
private List<User> userList = new ArrayList<>();
```

}

Some how code is not working. Executing everytime and returning nothing

```
package com.cts.pack.demojpa.controllertest;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

import com.cts.pack.thedailymuse.controller.CategoryController;
import com.cts.pack.thedailymuse.entity.Category;
import com.cts.pack.thedailymuse.entity.User;
import com.cts.pack.thedailymuse.exception.AlreadyFollowedException;
import com.cts.pack.thedailymuse.exception.CategoryNotFoundException;
import com.cts.pack.thedailymuse.exception.NotFollowedException;
import com.cts.pack.thedailymuse.exception.UserNotFoundException;
import com.cts.pack.thedailymuse.model.FollowUnfollowInputModel;
import com.cts.pack.thedailymuse.service.CategoryService;
import com.cts.pack.thedailymuse.service.UserService;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CategoryControllerTest {

    @Mock
    private CategoryService categoryService;

    @Mock
    private UserService userService;

    @InjectMocks
    private CategoryController categoryController;


    @Test
    public void testFollowCategory() throws AlreadyFollowedException, UserNotFoundException, CategoryNotFoundException {
        
        FollowUnfollowInputModel inputModel = new FollowUnfollowInputModel();
        inputModel.setCategory("example-category");
        inputModel.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        
        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryName("example-category");

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        when(categoryService.getCategory("example-category")).thenReturn(category);
        when(userService.getUser("user@example.com")).thenReturn(user);
        when(categoryService.addCategory(category)).thenReturn(category);

        ResponseEntity<Category> response = categoryController.followCategory(inputModel);

        assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, response.getStatusCode());
        assertEquals(category, response.getBody());
        verify(categoryService, times(1)).addCategory(category);
    }

    @Test(expected = UserNotFoundException.class)
    public void testFollowCategory_UserNotFoundException() throws AlreadyFollowedException, UserNotFoundException, CategoryNotFoundException {
        FollowUnfollowInputModel inputModel = new FollowUnfollowInputModel();
        inputModel.setCategory("example-category");
        inputModel.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryName("example-category");

        when(categoryService.getCategory("example-category")).thenReturn(category);
        when(userService.getUser("user@example.com")).thenReturn(null);

        categoryController.followCategory(inputModel);

    }

    @Test(expected = CategoryNotFoundException.class)
    public void testFollowCategory_CategoryNotFoundException() throws AlreadyFollowedException, UserNotFoundException, CategoryNotFoundException {
        FollowUnfollowInputModel inputModel = new FollowUnfollowInputModel();
        inputModel.setCategory("example-category");
        inputModel.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        when(categoryService.getCategory("example-category")).thenReturn(null);

        categoryController.followCategory(inputModel);

    }

    @Test(expected = AlreadyFollowedException.class)
    public void testFollowCategory_AlreadyFollowedException() throws AlreadyFollowedException, UserNotFoundException, CategoryNotFoundException {
        FollowUnfollowInputModel inputModel = new FollowUnfollowInputModel();
        inputModel.setCategory("example-category");
        inputModel.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryName("example-category");

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        when(categoryService.getCategory("example-category")).thenReturn(category);
        when(userService.getUser("user@example.com")).thenReturn(user);
        when(categoryService.addCategory(category)).thenReturn(category);

        categoryController.followCategory(inputModel);

    }

    @Test
    public void testUnfollowCategory() throws NotFollowedException, UserNotFoundException, CategoryNotFoundException {
        FollowUnfollowInputModel inputModel = new FollowUnfollowInputModel();
        inputModel.setCategory("example-category");
        inputModel.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryName("example-category");

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        when(categoryService.getCategory("example-category")).thenReturn(category);
        when(userService.getUser("user@example.com")).thenReturn(user);

        categoryController.unfollowCategory(inputModel);

        verify(categoryService, times(1)).removeCategory(category);
    }

    @Test(expected = UserNotFoundException.class)
    public void testUnfollowCategory_UserNotFoundException() throws NotFollowedException, UserNotFoundException, CategoryNotFoundException {
        FollowUnfollowInputModel inputModel = new FollowUnfollowInputModel();
        inputModel.setCategory("example-category");
        inputModel.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryName("example-category");

        when(categoryService.getCategory("example-category")).thenReturn(category);
        when(userService.getUser("user@example.com")).thenReturn(null);

        categoryController.unfollowCategory(inputModel);

    }

    @Test(expected = CategoryNotFoundException.class)
    public void testUnfollowCategory_CategoryNotFoundException() throws NotFollowedException, UserNotFoundException, CategoryNotFoundException {
        
        FollowUnfollowInputModel inputModel = new FollowUnfollowInputModel();
        inputModel.setCategory("example-category");
        inputModel.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        when(categoryService.getCategory("example-category")).thenReturn(null);

        categoryController.unfollowCategory(inputModel);

    }

    @Test(expected = NotFollowedException.class)
    public void testUnfollowCategory_NotFollowedException() throws NotFollowedException, UserNotFoundException, CategoryNotFoundException {

        FollowUnfollowInputModel inputModel = new FollowUnfollowInputModel();
        inputModel.setCategory("example-category");
        inputModel.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        Category category = new Category();
        category.setCategoryName("example-category");

        User user = new User();
        user.setEmailId("user@example.com");

        when(categoryService.getCategory("example-category")).thenReturn(category);
        when(userService.getUser("user@example.com")).thenReturn(user);

        categoryController.unfollowCategory(inputModel);

    }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FprBk.png)